# SQL query: Find latest from table with two dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table with a lot of entries, and I'm stuck on how to get the records with the latest "CreatedDate"

This is my table:

[image]

I would like this to be the result:

[image]

Date: Shows which date the quantity belongs to.

CreatedDate: Show the latest "Status" update and therefore I only need to latest record based on Createddate.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! `Status = 1`? It's not clear what the distinguishing feature of your desired result is? Also, please include tables and data as DDL and DML (dbfiddle.uk) and not as images - help us to help you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **window function** like [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to generate a unique series of IDs ordered by the `CreatedDate` if you want to partition by a specific field or criteria, but if there's nothing to partition on and you just want all records that have the globally latest `CreatedDate`, you can do that simpler with a CTE like so:

```
WITH CTE_CreatedDate_Latest AS
(
    SELECT MAX(CreatedDate) AS CreatedDate
    FROM YourTable
)

SELECT Y.Id, Y.Date, Y.CreatedDate, Y.CreatedByMemberId, Y.Quantity, Y.MemberId, Y.Status
FROM YourTable AS Y
INNER JOIN CTE_CreatedDate_Latest AS C
     ON Y.CreatedDate = C.CreatedDate
```